# How did Nansen plan to get home from the Fram expedition?

Tags: arctic

In 1893, the famed explorer [Fridtjof Nansen](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/peace/laureates/1922/nansen-bio.html) set out on [an expedition to reach the North Pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nansen's_Fram_expedition).  The plan was to sail a sturdy wooden ship, the *Fram*, into the ice north of Siberia, then drift, frozen in the sea ice, across the North Pole, coming out years later in the North Atlantic.

After almost *two years* in the ice, Nansen could see they weren't drifting far enough north to reach the Pole, so he and a single companion (Hjalmar Johansen) set out on skis.  After a month of skiing north, Nansen realized they weren't going to make it, so they turned around and headed south.

Since there was no way for them to find the *Fram*, they had to get home on their own.  It looks like their plan was to ski all the way to Svalbard, then board a ship headed for Norway.

---

But here's the problem -- there were no settlements in Svalbard in 1893, and no ships making regular trips to the archipelago that I could find.  **What exactly was Nansen's plan for getting home?**

As always, actual evidence makes for a better answer than guesswork.

---

<sup>The way he actually got home is as absurd as the expedition itself.  After nearly a year in the desolate and uninhabited Franz Josef Land, an unexplored archipelago the size of Serbia, the two men just happened to bump into someone -- and it was even someone Nansen knew personally, Frederick Jackson leading an unrelated expedition.  They got a ride back on Jackson's supply ship.</sup>

Comment: So, you are asking us what was going in the mind of a madman who died 86 years ago? You know this site is for FACTUAL questions, not speculating on the motions of spiders in the cranium of crazy dead people.

Comment: @TylerDurden, Nansen's plan was at least good enough that he received a grant from the Storting, and good enough that a crew of experienced explorers and scientists signed on to sail with him.

Answer (score 3):

From the Wikipedia page on [Svalbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard), the area was being used as a base for arctic exploration, so quite possibly he was hoping to run into another expedition that could evacuate him. Given that he walked across the ice-pack for a year it may not be as crazy as it sounds, though if he hadn't run into Jackson he would have had to wait until [1897](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._A._Andr%C3%A9e%27s_Arctic_Balloon_Expedition_of_1897).

Comment: And the two of them had already wintered in Franz Josef Land, so it seems they had adequate supplies of fresh water and food to last indefinitely.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable conjecture.  Know of any sources for the idea that Nansen was just hoping to run into another expedition?

Comment: @Joe - I have no source for the conjecture.